# Compose an ActiveRecord query having array of string conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, activerecord

I have an array of strings that are to serve as params for a `where` call in a model. 
How do I append each of the strings in the models `where` call and return the active record relation for an additional `limit` call

I have tried the following but it only adds the first item to the where clause

```
array = ['active = true', 'expired = false', 'created_at > 2017-04-18 10:36:28']
array.reduce { | item | Post.where(item) }
```

returns

```
Posts.where('active = true')
```

whereas am begging for

```
Posts.where('active = true').where('expired = false').where('created_at > 2017-04-18 10:36:28')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `join` array's elements into a single string:

```
array.join(' AND ')
#=> "active = true AND expired = false AND created_at > 2017-04-18 10:36:28"
```

And use it:

```
Post.where(array.join(' AND '))
```

P.S.

`created_at > 2017-04-18 10:36:28` will probably throw you a syntax error, but that's out of the question's scope.

Comment: You mean `AND`, not `,`, otherwise you need an hash

Comment: Good morning bro ^_^